# Animate stacked logo

Tags: css, animation, stacked

i have a logo which is cut into 8 pieces and i want the each piece get highlighted on mouse roll-over. Sadly my experience till now was that im only able to get the first layer highlighted because the ones underneethe the first one are blocked for role-over by the first layer  :(

any idea how i can make this work?

css

```
.logo {
    margin: -2.5% 0 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 75%;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="page-header d-flex align-items-center">
    <div>
        <img class="logo" src="{% static 'gfx/logo/logo_layers/logo_layer01.png' %}">
        <img class="logo" src="{% static 'gfx/logo/logo_layers/logo_layer02.png' %}">
        <img class="logo" src="{% static 'gfx/logo/logo_layers/logo_layer03.png' %}">
        <img class="logo" src="{% static 'gfx/logo/logo_layers/logo_layer04.png' %}">
        <img class="logo" src="{% static 'gfx/logo/logo_layers/logo_layer05.png' %}">
        <img class="logo" src="{% static 'gfx/logo/logo_layers/logo_layer06.png' %}">
        <img class="logo" src="{% static 'gfx/logo/logo_layers/logo_layer07.png' %}">
        <img class="logo" src="{% static 'gfx/logo/logo_layers/logo_layer08.png' %}">
    </div>
```

Comment: is this maybe possible trough svg? and if so, how?

Comment: can make this code working with the real image so we can see?

Comment: finally got it working as animated SVG but for some reason it animates just if i drag and drop it into chrome. if is integrate it on my website it simple does nothing?